# How do I use the log4net FileAppender under mono when running as a background process?

Tags: mono, log4net

I'm having trouble using a log4net `FileAppender` with mono.  If I spawn the processess in the background (i.e. `mono MyApp.exe &`), the process suspends after a short period of time.  If I run the process in the foreground, the logger works correctly.

On the other hand, if I use a `ConsoleAppender` and redirect it (i.e. `mono MyApp.exe > debug.log &`), things are fine.

Here is my configuration for the application:

```
<appender name="debug-log" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
  <file value="debug.log" />
  <appendToFile value="false" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%-8timestamp [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%-8timestamp [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>

<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="debug-log" />
</root>
```

I am using the mono-specific version of the log4net assembly.

**EDIT**

Mono version: 2.10.1

I just noticed another interesting behavior...  I am able to use the `FileAppender` to write to the debug-log as long as I redirect `stdout` anywhere.  For example, if I start my process using the following:

```
mono MyApp.exe > /dev/null &
```

The process executes normally, writing to the debug-log.  In this case, I am only using the debug-log, not the console appender.  Using the same configuration, the process will suspend after writing a small amount of data to debug-log when I remove the redirect.

Comment: Hi did you get anywhere on this? I've a similar issue -> can't get FileAppender working for a mono project on Mac....

Comment: Have you tried the RollingFileAppender?

Comment: @ÍlsonBolzan `RollingFileAppender` throws an error `System.NotImplementedException` on mono.